# Get object from list of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list, jakarta-ee, data-structures

I have a list of arrays of Object something like

```
 List arr has 
 object[0]
 object[1]
 .
 .
 .
 object[n]
```

where each object array has four elements like

object[0] has 1,2,a,4

how to get 1st element of first array of list?

I want to retrieve '1' from above example.

Comment: What does your object look like? Object[] object = new Object[n];
                    object[0] = new Object[]{1,2,'a',4};

Answer (score 1):

> how to get 1st element of first array of list?

```
       list.get(0)[0];
```

`list.get(0)` will get the array at zeroth index in the list. i.e., `Object[]` array and you access the first element of an array at zeroth index.

```
List<Object[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add(new Object[] {1,2,'a', 4});
System.out.println(arr.get(0)[0]);
```

produces 1 as output

Comment: I think OP has an array of array, rather than a java.util.List of array. But maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think without casting it may not work since OP has `list of array of Objects`

Comment: @anubhava check my edit. it worked for me (hoping i understood OP's question ) :P

Answer (score 1):

First, get the first element of the list with the `get` method.  Assuming that `arr` is not declared using generics, cast it as an `Object[]` (object array), because it is an object array.  Then use array syntax to get the first element from the array.

```
Object desired = ((Object[]) arr.get(0))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast first element to an array like this:

```
 String[] arr1 = (String[]) object[0];
```

Then extract 1st element from arr1 using `arr1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<Object[]> list = //filled in somewhere

if(list.size() > 0) {
    if(list.get(0).length > 0) {
        System.out.prinln(list.get(0)[0].toString());
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the Object[] arrays contain numbers and strings.

Answer (score -1):

You get the first element of the first array this way:

```
object[0][0]
```

Edit: I assumed you have an array of array. If you have a java.util.List of array, please look at PermGenError's answer.